# Was the villain of Justice League Dark based on a Sandman villain?

Tags: dc, inspiration, the-sandman, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-dark

The main villain of the movie *Justice League Dark* features a sprit who

> calls himself Destiny and uses a dream rock to make people live their worst fears.

In the *24 Hour* Sandman story, the main villain is a man who

> calls himself Dr. Destiny and uses a dream rock to control people

**Did *24 Hour* inspire *Justice League Dark*, or is this just an interesting coincidence?**

Comment: I vaguely recall *Sandman's* Dr. Destiny as himself based off an older supervillain.  Of course, the same arc had him escaping from Arkham Asylum and having homey chats with Dr. Crane / Scarecrow, so....

Comment: @Radhil He is, but not in this context. He is just a villain in the normal Justice League comics.

Comment: Are you certain of that? From what I can tell, Doctor Destiny is the same character in normal DC stories as well as the Sandman stories, and uses the Materioptikon (Dreamstone).

Comment: @CreationEdge Just did a little research, you are right. my bad

Comment: On a side note, it looks like some people are [adapting Sandman](http://www.themarysue.com/joseph-gordon-levitt-talks-sandman/)

Comment: [JGL quit the Sandman production last year](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2016/mar/07/joseph-gordon-levitt-quits-adaptation-neil-gaiman-sandman) and then [the writer did too](http://www.theverge.com/2016/11/4/13517450/sandman-writer-quits-only-tv-neil-gaiman).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**He was a JLA villain long before Sandman met him.**

[Doctor Destiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Destiny) is a classic Justice League villain who used various inventions of his own design to battle the JLA. One of them, an invention called the Materioptikon allowed him to enter and control dreams. He eventually learned that he could engage in [Lucid Dreaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucid_dream) and use a "Dream Materioptikon" to achieve the same ends. He made many appearances in classic JLA issues in the Silver Age.

When Neil Gaiman wrote his version of Sandman, he had Dream's three tools of power fall into nefarious hands. Doctor Destiny obtained his Dream Ruby, which increased his own power greatly when interfaced with a new version of the Materioptikon.